# 'shp2pgsql' is not recognized : command not found error

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to import shape file to postgis. I have problem configuring shp2pgsql.

I am getting this error :

```
-bash: shp2pgsql: command not found
```

I have read different threads without getting any results like: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/19213

```
macbook$ locate shp2pgsql
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/PostGIS/man/shp2pgsql.1
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/shp2pgsql
/usr/bin/shp2pgsql

macbook$ otool -L shp2psql
otool: can't open file: shp2psql (No such file or directory)
```

I tried to run which command

```
macbook$ which shp2pgsql
```

I got nothing .

```
 macbook$ ls /usr/bin/shp2pgsql
/usr/bin/shp2pgsql
```

First guess was that "shp2pgsql" is not linked. How can I link /usr/bin/shp2pgsql in postgres PostgreSQL when I tried to run :

```
sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/shp2pgsql  /usr/bin/shp2pgsql
It says that : : ln: /usr/bin/shp2pgsql: File exists
```

**UPDATE**
When I linked shp2pgsql

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/liblwgeom-2.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/shp2pgsql
  Reason: image not found
```

When i tried to locate liblwgeom

```
macbook$ locate liblwgeom
/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/liblwgeom.brewing
/Library/Caches/Homebrew/liblwgeom-2.1.1.tar.gz
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/postgresql/liblwgeom-2.1.1.dylib
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/postgresql/liblwgeom.a
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/postgresql/liblwgeom.dylib
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/postgresql/liblwgeom.la
/usr/local/Cellar/liblwgeom
/usr/local/Cellar/liblwgeom/2.1.1
/usr/local/Cellar/liblwgeom/2.1.1/COPYING
/usr/local/Cellar/liblwgeom/2.1.1/ChangeLog
/usr/local/Cellar/liblwgeom/2.1.1/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
/usr/local/Cellar/liblwgeom/2.1.1/LICENSE.TXT
/usr/local/Cellar/liblwgeom/2.1.1/NEWS
/usr/local/Cellar/liblwgeom/2.1.1/TODO
/usr/local/Cellar/liblwgeom/2.1.1/include
/usr/local/Cellar/liblwgeom/2.1.1/include/liblwgeom.h
/usr/local/Cellar/liblwgeom/2.1.1/lib
/usr/local/Cellar/liblwgeom/2.1.1/lib/liblwgeom-2.1.1.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/liblwgeom/2.1.1/lib/liblwgeom.a
/usr/local/Cellar/liblwgeom/2.1.1/lib/liblwgeom.dylib
/usr/local/Library/Formula/liblwgeom.rb
/usr/local/opt/liblwgeom
```

Any thoughts how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Write echo $PATH in your bash console and tell us what it says.
Probably this can be fixed by

```
PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/
export PATH
```

Comment: Thanks!it seems that I have missing file (Check first UPDATE). It's the same here : https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/19213. But it's not resolved in the post